# Button click event firing alternativly using event and delegate

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button, delegates

I am using `delegates`.

In my code, i am calling button event through `delegates`. But `button click` is firing alternatively...

In each `button click`, it is go to page load, but not going to button click event function.
It go to `event function`  alternate.

Comment: In which event you are setting event delegate to button?

Comment: button click event set as event delegates